# How to change the animation of agents when using same ResourcePool in two services

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a ResourcePool that contains 5 agents. Now I am using 2 agents in the first service and 3 agents in the second service.

[image]

**Properties section of First service**
[image]

**Properties section of Second service**
[image]

However, the animation of agents is always set to 3. Shown in image below.
[image]

**What I want** is when first service is in use I see only 2 agents and when second service is in use I see 3 agents.

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by "the animation of agents is always set to 2"? Best add screenshots by default to explain your points :)

Comment: I edited the question and add all the relevant images. kindly take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use different nodes to animate the different service blocks. You currently use the same node and all 5 are likely drawn on top of each other...